# Chart.js yAxis hidden data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a problem with `Chart.js`. From the picture, you can see that chart hide my horizontal line draw with annotation

```
           annotation: {
                annotations: [{
                    drawTime: 'afterDraw', 
                    type: 'line',
                    mode: 'horizontal',
                    scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                    value: chartData.test,
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    label: {
                        content: "Test",
                        enabled: true,
                        position: "left"
                    }
                }]
            }
```

[image]

So the problem is how to tell `Chart.js` to set yAxis max over this value, also I don't want to calculate max value because I have I lot of data, this is just example